# How to share node modules folder between different react applications

Tags: reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I have a few react applications, for each application, I am installing dependencies which I mentioned in package.json(node_modules) and for all applications, these dependencies are the same.

If in this case, why do I maintain the same duplicate files in multiple places, and also it is a waste of memory.

Is there any way to install all my package.json dependencies at one location and to share it between the components?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is reasonable to keep duplicating different package.json files for different applications.

However I think it is possible to create an npm package that would include all your dependencies and then make your project just to use this one npm package.